# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

"Благодаря глупому эгоизму() у меня теперь нет ни друзей, ни близких." Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обороты с предлогами "благодаря","согласно", "вопреки" обособляются факультативно и зависят от степени распространенности оборота, его смысловой близости к основной части предложения, занимаемого им места по отношению к сказуемому, наличия добавочных обстоятельственных значений, стилистических задач и т. п. Среди подобных конструкций обособляется обязательно только оборот с предложным сочетанием несмотря на.

В данном предложении обособление вполне допустимо, здесь причинное значение, пояснение. Только сам предлог обычно употребляется с фактами положительного смысла, а не отрицательного, а глупый эгоизм - отрицательный факт, может, лучше сказать "из-за глупого эгоизма"?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая скорее не нужна. Одно из условий обособления - позиция не в начале и не в конце предложения. В начале предложения такие обороты обычно не обособляются.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/